# Error:552 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using **JavaMail** for sending an *e-mail Correspondence* in an application.

Sending an e-mail Correspondence by adding multiple files as attachemnts (***10-12 Files***) all file size is between *4-5MB*.

Result:e-mail correspondence is getting failed.

**Error Logs :**

```
<param1 - com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 552 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed maximum message size

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:586)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:119)
    at com.framework.services.mail.Mailer.send(Mailer.java:237)
    at com.framework.services.mail.Mailer.sendMail(Mailer.java:412)
    at com.framework.services.mail.MailServiceImpl.sendMail(MailServiceImpl.java:50)
    at com.agx.util.ost.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:211)
    at com.agx.scheduler.CorrespondenceSchedulerJob.sendCorrespondence(CorrespondenceSchedulerJob.java:4612)
    at com.agx.scheduler.CorrespondenceSchedulerJob.startCorrespondenceScheduler(CorrespondenceSchedulerJob.java:236)
    at com.agx.scheduler.CorrespondenceSchedulerJob.execute(CorrespondenceSchedulerJob.java:224)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
>
```

What is the cause of above error?

Thanks!

Comment: Please any and all help appreciated. I've exhausted the google search engine.

Comment: Which was the solution in your case? smaller messages or reconfiguration of the mail server ?

Comment: @Victor  Configured mail server to accept larger messages.

Comment: I believe you are talking about the _maxmessagesize_ property from the _config.xml_ file (as mentioned here - https://james.apache.org/server/2.3.0/smtp_configuration.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is telling you that your message is too big.  Change the configuration of your server to allow larger messages, or send smaller messages.